# Rename specific string from filename using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have to rename the filename with some specific keywords changed.

```
**Input FileName :**
master_1800_20181217120005.csv
master_2300_20181217120005.csv
master_2300_addcarrier_20181217120005.csv
master_2300_XNB_20181217120005.csv
master_2300_XNB_addcarrier_20181217120005.csv
master_850_20181217120005.csv
master_850_addcarrier_20181217120005.csv
master_IBS_20181217120005.csv
master_Smallcell_20181217000500.csv
```

**Output FileName:**
*master_1800_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_2300_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_2300_addcarrier_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_2300_XNB_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_2300_XNB_addcarrier_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_850_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_850_addcarrier_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_IBS_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`120005.csv
master_Smallcell_`$(date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)`000500.csv*

I tried using `$(rename 's/20181217/20181218/' )` but no luck.

Comment: what's your error? I would imagine something from here would do the trick: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121583

Comment: The command substitution `$(rename ...)` is wrong unless you expect `rename` to print a command which your shell should then execute.

Answer (score 1):

`rename 20181217 20181218 master_*.csv` might do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This work: rename 's/20181217/20181218/' YOUR_FILE_NAME

Or you can use sed, before you redirect you output to the target file.